# C# saxonapi.Evaluate taking too long to run Xquery on 500MB XML with 13Million lines

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xquery, saxon

Application compiled 64bit running on 4CPU 16GBRAM. SaxonApi.Evaluate is taking 47 minutes of total time (60 Minutes) for 3 Evaluate calls on 500MB xml file with 13 million lines.  Every Evaluate runs a XQuery which returns 80,000 items and each item has 20 nodes.

Is there anything we have do to improve the SaxonApi.Evaluate method

Comment: You will not receive proper answers without example data and code. There are too many aspects relevant here.

Comment: You should be using XmlReader on file this large.  See my sample code at this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips you may find helpful:

- Measure how the query performance varies with source document size. Is it linear or quadratic? If it's quadratic, that's probably because you are doing a join of some kind. If it's a simple join, then the Saxon-EE optimizer will probably give a substantial boost - download an evaluation and give it a try.
- With performance, the devil is in the detail. To explain the performance you are getting, we need to know every detail of what you are doing, to the extent that we can reproduce the results ourselves. Telling us you have a query that takes a long time, without even showing the query, is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Sure.. If I send Xquery and document format will you be able to generate a large file...                                                                                                            Let me try to get some more details. Thanks Michael. .

Answer (score 0):

Pasted Sample XML and Xquery I am using. There are 80K /Top/level1/Sch3K1 in the  Large XML.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Top>
    <level1>        
        <Sch3K1>
            <PartnershipInformation>
                <PartnershipName>Partner1</PartnershipName>
                <PartnershipFEIN>XXXXXXX</PartnershipFEIN>
                <PartnerAddress>
                    <USAddress>
                        <AddressLine1Txt>xxxx</AddressLine1Txt>
                        <CityNm>City</CityNm>
                        <StateAbbreviationCd>MO</StateAbbreviationCd>
                        <ZIPCd>1111</ZIPCd>
                    </USAddress>
                </PartnerAddress>
            </PartnershipInformation>
            <PartnerInformation>
                <Individual>
                    <PartnerName>
                        <FirstName>Partner1 FName</FirstName>
                        <MiddleInitial>P</MiddleInitial>
                        <LastName>Partner1 LName</LastName>
                    </PartnerName>
                    <PartnerSSN>XXXXXX</PartnerSSN>
                </Individual>
                <PartnerAddress>
                    <USAddress>
                        <AddressLine1Txt>318 Some STREET</AddressLine1Txt>
                        <CityNm>City2</CityNm>
                        <StateAbbreviationCd>WY</StateAbbreviationCd>
                        <ZIPCd>2222</ZIPCd>
                    </USAddress>
                </PartnerAddress>
                <LimitedPartner>X</LimitedPartner>
                <DomesticPartner>X</DomesticPartner>
                <PartnersProfitBOY>0.00003779</PartnersProfitBOY>
                <PartnersProfitEOY>0.0000319</PartnersProfitEOY>
                <PartnersLossBOY>0.00003779</PartnersLossBOY>
                <PartnersLossEOY>0.0000319</PartnersLossEOY>
                <PartnersCapitalBOY>0.00003779</PartnersCapitalBOY>
                <PartnersCapitalEOY>0.0000319</PartnersCapitalEOY>
                <PartnersLiabilitiesNonrecourse>0</PartnersLiabilitiesNonrecourse>
                <PartnersLiabilitiesQNF>0</PartnersLiabilitiesQNF>
                <PartnersLiabilitiesRecourse>0</PartnersLiabilitiesRecourse>
                <CapitalAccountBeginning>1858311</CapitalAccountBeginning>
                <CapitalAccountIncrease>137711</CapitalAccountIncrease>
                <CapitalAccountWithdrawls>646011</CapitalAccountWithdrawls>
                <CapitalAccountEnding>1350011</CapitalAccountEnding>
                <CapitalAccountMethod>
                    <TaxBasis>X</TaxBasis>
                </CapitalAccountMethod>
                <PartnerStateRes>WY</PartnerStateRes>
                <ByApportionment>X</ByApportionment>
                <ApportionmentPercentage>0.0360504</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartnerInformation>
            <PartnersShare>
                <OrdinaryIncome>
                    <FederalAmount>111</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>111</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>29</StateSourceNonRes>
                </OrdinaryIncome>
                <NetIncomeRentalRE/>
                <NetIncomeRentalNonRE>
                    <FederalAmount>700</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>700</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>25</StateSourceNonRes>
                </NetIncomeRentalNonRE>
                <GuaranteedPymts/>
                <InterestIncome>
                    <FederalAmount>12</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>12</PerStateLaw>
                </InterestIncome>
                <OrdinaryDividends/>
                <RoyaltyIncome/>
                <ShortTermCapGain>
                    <FederalAmount>3</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>3</PerStateLaw>
                </ShortTermCapGain>
                <LongTermCapGain>
                    <FederalAmount>15</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>15</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>1</StateSourceNonRes>
                </LongTermCapGain>
                <NetSection1231Gain>
                    <FederalAmount>475</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>475</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>17</StateSourceNonRes>
                </NetSection1231Gain>
                <AttributableToSaleFarmAssets/>
                <OtherIncome>
                    <FederalAmount>-596</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>-596</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>-21</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>Other income</Explanation>
                </OtherIncome>
                <Sec179Deduction/>
                <OtherDeductions>
                    <FederalAmount>12</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>12</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>Total Other Deductions</Explanation>
                </OtherDeductions>
                <ForeignTransactions>
                    <FederalAmount>64338</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>64338</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>GrossIncomeFromAllSources</Explanation>
                </ForeignTransactions>
                <ForeignTransactions>
                    <FederalAmount>170</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>170</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>GeneralCategorySourcedAtPartnershipLevel</Explanation>
                </ForeignTransactions>
                <ForeignTransactions>
                    <FederalAmount>151</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>151</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>GeneralCategoryApportionedAtPartnerLevel</Explanation>
                </ForeignTransactions>
                <ForeignTransactions>
                    <FederalAmount>5</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>5</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>TotalForeignTaxes</Explanation>
                </ForeignTransactions>
                <AltMinTax>
                    <FederalAmount>480</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>480</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>17</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>Post 1986 depreciation adjustment</Explanation>
                </AltMinTax>
                <AltMinTax>
                    <FederalAmount>-636</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>-636</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>-23</StateSourceNonRes>
                    <Explanation>Adjusted gain or loss</Explanation>
                </AltMinTax>
                <NondeductibleExpenses>
                    <FederalAmount>31</FederalAmount>
                    <PerStateLaw>31</PerStateLaw>
                </NondeductibleExpenses>
                <Distributions>
                    <DistSecurities>
                        <FederalAmount>6460</FederalAmount>
                        <PerStateLaw>6460</PerStateLaw>
                    </DistSecurities>
                </Distributions>
                <OtherInformation>
                    <InvestmentIncome>
                        <FederalAmount>12</FederalAmount>
                        <Adjustment>12</Adjustment>
                        <StateSourceNonRes>0</StateSourceNonRes>
                        <Explanation>Investment Income</Explanation>
                    </InvestmentIncome>
                </OtherInformation>
                <IncomeLossReconciliation>
                    <PerStateLaw>1413</PerStateLaw>
                    <StateSourceNonRes>51</StateSourceNonRes>
                </IncomeLossReconciliation>
                <GrossIncomeAllActivities/>
            </PartnersShare>
            <PartnersApportionmentFactors>
                <FirstFactor>
                    <FactorUsed>Property</FactorUsed>
                    <Wisconsin>0</Wisconsin>
                    <TotalCompany>0</TotalCompany>
                </FirstFactor>
                <SecondFactor>
                    <FactorUsed>Payroll</FactorUsed>
                    <Wisconsin>0</Wisconsin>
                    <TotalCompany>0</TotalCompany>
                </SecondFactor>
                <ThirdFactor>
                    <FactorUsed>Sales</FactorUsed>
                    <Wisconsin>0</Wisconsin>
                    <TotalCompany>0</TotalCompany>
                </ThirdFactor>
            </PartnersApportionmentFactors>
            <PartnersShareAddSub>
                <Additions>
                    <TotalAdditions>0</TotalAdditions>
                </Additions>
                <Subtractions>
                    <TotalSubtractions>0</TotalSubtractions>
                </Subtractions>
                <TotalAdjustment>0</TotalAdjustment>
            </PartnersShareAddSub>
        </Sch3K1>   
    </level1>   
</Top>
```

**XQuery**

```
for 
    $level1 at $currentlevel1Pos in if(exists(./x:top/x:level1)) then ./x:top/x:level1 else element{'level1'} {''},
    $Sch3K1 at $currentSch3K1Pos in if(exists(./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1)) then ./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1 else element{'Sch3K1'} {''},
    $PartnerInformation at $currentPartnerInformationPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation else element{'PartnerInformation'} {''},
    $PartnersProfitBOY at $currentPartnersProfitBOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY else element{'PartnersProfitBOY'} {''},
    $PartnersProfitEOY at $currentPartnersProfitEOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY else element{'PartnersProfitEOY'} {''},
    $PartnersLossBOY at $currentPartnersLossBOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY else element{'PartnersLossBOY'} {''},
    $PartnersLossEOY at $currentPartnersLossEOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY else element{'PartnersLossEOY'} {''},
    $PartnersCapitalBOY at $currentPartnersCapitalBOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY else element{'PartnersCapitalBOY'} {''},
    $PartnersCapitalEOY at $currentPartnersCapitalEOYPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY)) then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY else element{'PartnersCapitalEOY'} {''}

let $genlevel1 := false
let $genSch3K1 := false
let $prevSch3K1 := ./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+-1]
let $nextSch3K1 := ./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+1]
let $Sch3K1Count := count(./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1)
let $genPartnerInformation := false
let $genPartnersProfitBOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY)
let $genPartnersProfitEOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY)
let $genPartnersLossBOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY)
let $genPartnersLossEOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY)
let $genPartnersCapitalBOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY)
let $genPartnersCapitalEOY := exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY)
return 
<Evaluation>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersProfitBOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitBOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersProfitEOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersProfitEOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersLossBOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossBOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersLossEOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersLossEOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersCapitalBOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalBOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
    <FieldEntry>
            <Name>x:PartnersCapitalEOY</Name>
            <Xpath>x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY</Xpath>
            <Value>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY/data()}</Value>
            <NextValue>{$nextSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY/data()}</NextValue>
            <PrevValue>{$prevSch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY/data()}</PrevValue>
            <Index>{$currentSch3K1Pos}</Index>
            <Count>{$Sch3K1Count}</Count>
            <FieldKey>{$Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation/x:PartnersCapitalEOY/@FieldKey/data()}</FieldKey>
            <NodeIsPresent></NodeIsPresent>
            <HasChildNodes></HasChildNodes>
            </FieldEntry>
</Evaluation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are a few anomalies here.

- The query won't compile because it uses a namespace prefix "x" that hasn't been declared. (But the source document doesn't appear to use a namespace)
- The query refers to the top-level element as `x:top` but in the source document it is `Top`
- A couple of variables are bound to `false` when surely `false()` is intended (Saxon gives a warning about this).

Secondly, there are many variables being declared that are not used. For example, `$PartnersCapitalBOY` and `$genPartnersCapitalBOY`. In principle it's easy enough for an optimizer to ignore variables that aren't used, but giving an optimizer unnecessary work to do isn't always a good idea, because it can distract it from finding the patterns where optimization can make a real difference.

Thirdly, I'm suspicious about the repeated use of the construct:

```
(for) $PartnerInformation at $currentPartnerInformationPos 
 in if(exists($Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation)) 
    then $Sch3K1/x:PartnerInformation 
    else element{'PartnerInformation'} {''},
```

The problem here is that constructs that create a new element can't be moved out of a loop, because XQuery is very fussy about the fact that such a construct must create a different element every time it is executed. So (without actually examining what the optimizer does in detail) I would suspect that this construct inhibits the optimizations that are possible.

Fourth, the clauses:

```
let $prevSch3K1 := ./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+-1]
let $nextSch3K1 := ./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+1]
```

might be more efficient if `./x:top/x:level1/x:Sch3K1` is bound to a global variable.

At first sight your query is absolutely horrendous, with 9 nested loops each iterating over 80K elements: a naive implementation would execute the innermost code around 10^45 times, so if the innermost code takes one nanosecond to execute, the total query would take 10^36 seconds, which given that the age of the universe is less than 10^16 seconds, is rather a long time. So if this is running in an hour, the optimizer has done a pretty good job.

The only reason it is able to do such a good job is that so much of the query is obviously pointless.

Looking at the optimizer trace (-explain) I'm actually surprised how few optimizations are being done, and I suspect the main cause of this is the element constructors in the middle of the "for" clauses.

I would start by simplifying the query:

1. Eliminate all the unused variables
2. If you really need to create the dummy elements in order to achieve an outer join, create these dummy elements once as global variables rather than creating them repeatedly within the loop.

With these changes, the logic may become clearer. I think that in essence, it's actually a very simple query.

Comment: There was a typo in the Source document, it should be top. Regarding the /x:, it is replaced with the  namespace from the source document in run time.                                                                                                              I will follow your suggestions and look into improving the XQuery... Thanks and appreciate for the detailed explanation and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As per Michael Kay suggestions, I changed the FLWOR statement using global variables for constructs and some variable assignments. No change to the return statement and didn't include below. When I run the Query.exe, takes 21 minutes with changes when compared to 24 minutes to return the result. There's slight improvement. Saving Result to a file is 150 MB... so is there anything I am missing. Thanks

```
let $docxml := doc("p.xml")
let $gSch3K1 := $docxml/Top/level1/Sch3K1
let $glevel1Element := element{'level1'} {''}
let $gSch3K1Element := element{'Sch3K1'} {''}
let $gPartnerInformationElement := element{'PartnerInformation'} {''}


for     
    $level1 at $currentlevel1Pos in if(exists($docxml/Top/level1)) then $docxml/Top/level1 else $glevel1Element,
    $Sch3K1 at $currentSch3K1Pos in if(exists($docxml/Top/level1/Sch3K1)) then $docxml/Top/level1/Sch3K1 else $gSch3K1Element,
    $PartnerInformation at $currentPartnerInformationPos in if(exists($Sch3K1/PartnerInformation)) then $Sch3K1/PartnerInformation else $gPartnerInformationElement

let $prevSch3K1 := $gSch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+-1]
let $nextSch3K1 := $gSch3K1[$currentSch3K1Pos+1]
let $Sch3K1Count := count($docxml/Top/level1/Sch3K1)

return
---
```

Comment: Made a small change to variable $Sch3K1Count which gets count in above and got the result in less than 1 minute.  `code`  let $Sch3K1Count := count($gSch3K1)